# Cancelling the MS Access SpellCheck dialog with {ESC} key causes subform updating error #NAME

Tags: ms-access, vba

In MS Access 2013, I have a form with several subforms.  On one of the subforms is a RichText multiline textbox.  The user can click a button to spellcheck the textbox, and, the textbox is also automatically spellchecked when a [Save] button on the subform is clicked.

The spellcheck works fine.  But, if the user presses {ESCAPE} when the spellcheck dialog appears in order to dismiss the dialog, the data in a different subform does not get updated properly and shows #NAME for all fields.

But, if the user presses the [Cancel] button or clicks the [X] at the top right of the dialog to close the spellcheck dialog, the subform gets updated just fine.

Furthermore, if I put in a breakpoint right after the command that calls the spellcheck dialog and then step through the code line by line, the subform gets updated just fine even when the {ESC} key is pressed.

I tried moving the spellcheck to the form's AfterUpdate event instead of the [Save] button's OnClick event but that didn't change the problem.

**Does anyone know a graceful way of preventing the use of {ESC} to dismiss the spellcheck dialog from preventing other subforms from updating correctly?**

I've posted an answer in case it helps someone out, but, I'd love it someone posted/suggested a more elegant solution because I don't particularly like my workaround.  I'll wait awhile before marking my answer as accepted so others can post a better one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the sloppy workaround that worked for me was to add a `SendKeys "{RIGHT}", True` after the Spellcheck command as follows:

```
'spell check the progress note
If Me.[Note].Tag = "Locked" Then
    MsgBox "Cannot spell check a locked note.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Locked"
Else
    'If the Note contains data run the Spell Checker after data is entered.
     If Len(Me.[Note] & "") > 0 Then
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        Me.[Note].SetFocus  'set focus to the control to spell check
        With Me.[Note]
            .SelStart = 0
            .SelLength = Len(Me.[Note])
            DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSpelling
            SendKeys "{RIGHT}", True
            .SelLength = 0
        End With
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
     End If
End If
```

I think this is sloppy and should not be necessary and I have no idea why it solves the problem.  So, **I'd love it if someone else provides a more elegant solution!**

Comment: After a week there were no other suggestions, so, I'm marking it as the answer.  Hope the above answer helps someone out.  

If anyone else has ideas, please feel free to post!